# Arch linux and Gnome tap to click does not work

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, tap

I am a bit new to arch linux and am having trouble getting tap to click to work. I am not completely sure how the stuff works so I am going to tell you what I did. Firstly, after the basic arch install I installed Gnome and enabled gdm with systemctl. I have xorg, synaptics and libinput installed and have edited the /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/ file and it looks like this:

```
Section "InputClass"
Identifier "touchpad"
Driver "synaptics"
MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    Option "TapButton1" "1"
    Option "TapButton2" "3"
    Option "TapButton3" "2"
    Option "VertEdgeScroll" "on"
    Option "VertTwoFingerScroll" "on"
    Option "HorizEdgeScroll" "on"
    Option "HorizTwoFingerScroll" "on"
    Option "CircularScrolling" "on"
    Option "CircScrollTrigger" "2"
    Option "EmulateTwoFingerMinZ" "40"
    Option "EmulateTwoFingerMinW" "8"
    Option "CoastingSpeed" "0"
    Option "FingerLow" "30"
    Option "FingerHigh" "50"
    Option "MaxTapTime" "125"
    ...
EndSection
```

When I type sudo startx X starts but I get three white terminal windows and my pc freezes. Do you guys know what I am doing wrong?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Uninstall `xf86-input-synaptics` and *don't* start X with elevated privileges...

Comment: Or remove the `xorg.conf` section (xorg can detect it pretty well), keep `xf86-input-synaptics` and add the options and use `synclient` in `.xinitrc` to set the options.

Comment: When I run synclient in the console it tells me that no synaptics driver was loaded. I tried putting it in .xinitrc but nothing happened.